# Pattern match list with 3-element arrays, and replace entries

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

```
list = {
  {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, 
  {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, 
  {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, 
  {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1} ,{1, 0, 1},{1, 0, 1}
};
```

The list always has two 1s and one zero. I want to replace the 0s (position 1, 2 or 3 within element) that change to 1 in next element, with minus 1. This would give list2 below.

```
list2 = {
  {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, 
  {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, 
  {**-1**, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, **-1**}, 
  {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 1} ,{1, 0, 1},{1, 0, 1}
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};

Join[Subtract @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1] /. {1 -> 0}, {{0, 0, 0}}] + list
```

> {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}

Comment: Thanks that work perfectly!   I am still deciphering fully how it works, but excellent idea to add the original list as the zeros don't change the minus one! Thanks again!

Comment: OK I think I've upvote/accepted now.

Answer (score 4):

A replacement-based approach, with minimal pre- and post-processing of the list:

```
list = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};
Transpose@list /. {a___, 0, 1, b___} :> {a, -1, 1, b} // Transpose
(* {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks that is useful,  with minimal pre- and post-processing, there is less risk of something going awry.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};
```

Using `ArrayReduce` (new in 12.2) and the operator form of
`SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

```
ArrayReduce[SequenceReplace[{0, 1} :> Sequence[-1, 1]], list, 2]
```

{{-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}}

With `ArrayReduce` we don't need `Map` and the double transposition

```
Transpose @ Map[SequenceReplace[{0, 1} :> Sequence[-1, 1]], Transpose @ list]
```

{{-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};
```

Using `ReplaceAll` and a `Do` loop:

```
Module[{l = list, n = Length@list},
Do[If[Unequal[l[[i]], l[[i + 1]]], 
l[[i]] = ReplaceAll[l[[i]], {0 -> -1}];], {i, n - 1}];l]

(*{{-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}*)
```